# Client wise Report using SAP Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, crystal-reports

I have created an application to generate invoice Using SAP Crystal Reports.But the problem is that whenever I add a new client,his report is appended to the previous report one after the other.What I am trying to achieve is to get the invoice client wise to a PDF File and then print.

But when I add the First Report,Everything along with the Report Title is displayed perfectly.But when I add another record and click on the next page,The title of the project disappears ieThe 2nd report gets appended to the 1st

Can anyone tell me how to achieve this and the approach for doing it?

Thanks,

Comment: How are you providing data to report? Give some code related to the question, so we can see what might have gotten wrong.

Comment: @L16H7 Thanks for replying.I just fixed the issue by formatting the report,there was no issue with the code as such